# Configure sonarqube for Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to configure SonarQube with Codename One project on Netbeans. I am able to generate code complexity and Rule compliance report. But sonar is unable to identify unit test cases. Any special steps required for unit testing coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SonarQube at all so I'm not sure if this will help but Codename One does have a unit test API of its own and test recorder that is probably not supported by SonarQube: http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2012/12/test-it.html

The reason for not using JUnit and other such harnesses is that they usually rely on reflection to get the job done and that's a problem for on device testing across platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do we have any test case code coverage reporting tool for CN1?

Comment: No. But some Java SE tools might work for Codename One when running on the simulator.